# Character set mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  a.ColumnA, b.ColumnB || 
 CASE WHEN TRIM(c.ColumnC) IS NOT NULL THEN ' (' || c.ColumnC || ')' ELSE '' END AS ClassName
 FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.SomeColumn = b.SomeColumn 
 INNER JOIN TableC c on a.SomeCol = c.SomeCol
```

I'm getting an error "Character set mismatch" at the " ELSE '' " part of the CASE expression.
Can someone suggest where I'm doing it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: How are columns ColumnB and ColumnC defined? 
Does the query work without the ELSE clause?

Comment: There's no problem with the statement (assume the last join is also on the a,b SomeColumn and you just abbreviated the column name).  Could you update the question with the database character set info?

Comment: I've found the answer. We need to CAST the ELSE part with the same type as the ColumnC. May be that way it knows the datatype of the outcome of the CASE expression. 

So, it is: CASE WHEN ...... ELSE CAST('' AS NVarchar2(1)) END

Comment: So Plasmer's  comment/question was the clue - we didn't know that c.ColumnC was NVARCHAR2 - most would just assume varchar2 when reading your question - glad you found the workaround

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate VARCHAR and NVARCHAR values without a CAST statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(c.ColumnC) IS NOT NULL 
     THEN ' (' || c.ColumnC || ')' 
     ELSE N'' END A
```

is a more concise solution. N'' gives you a unicode empty string

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing '' with NULL? 
Also, try removing ELSE part altogether because it will return NULL anyway.

Comment: The intention is to append the value from ColumnC, if exists, to ColumnB. If I replace the ELSE part with NULL, then the entire value will become NULL (b.ColumnB || NULL = NULL) and I don't want that.

Comment: Not true.

select 'a'||null from dual;

returns 'a'

Comment: Also, empty string constant ('') is just a way to write "to_char(NULL)".

Answer (score 0):

Just erase the ELSE, would make your code easier to read